# recursive muc creation possibility for openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Is it possible to create recursive muc for openfire under default service "conference"? some thing like:

groupchat1
   -groupchata
   -groupchatb
   -groupchatc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Openfire implements XEP-0045: Multi-User Chat, look at http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html,  Exist many libraries available for many different programming languages to connect the XMPP server(Openfire is a XMPP server) look at http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/, I recommend you to use [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/). 
Smack is developed by the creators of Openfire.